# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando implementar o VLibras: https://vlibras.gov.br/doc/widget/installation/webpageintegration.html

Onde é necessário apenas copiar o código da documentação e colocar dentro do body.
Em páginas de testes, apenas com o código ele funciona perfeitamente, porém quando vou usar no meu index.php principal, a ferramenta não aparece e da erro no console do navegador, como pode ser visto abaixo.
[image: erro mencionado]

e o meu código é esse, exatamente o que tem na documentação e funciona em páginas testes.

```
    <div vw class="enabled">
        <div vw-access-button class="active"></div>
        <div vw-plugin-wrapper>
        <div class="vw-plugin-top-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://vlibras.gov.br/app/vlibras-plugin.js"></script>
    <script>
        new window.VLibras.Widget('https://vlibras.gov.br/app');
    </script>
```

Provavelmente está dando conflito com algum outro elemento, em uma página teste eu tentei testar com meus scripts principais e a função

> window.onload

Estava fazendo ele desaparecer, mas em meu index.php principal continuou dando erro mesmo após a remoção da função...

Mas o que seriam esses dois erros que estão mostrando no console do navegador?

Comment: precisa revisar seu codigo javascript, esse erro diz que em algum ponto falta fechar uma chave, parênteses, aspas, etc

Answer (score 0):

Sua página index.php provavelmente está com um charset diferente de UTF-8. Pra resolver o problema adicione charset="UTF-8" no carregamento do seu script ficando assim:

```html
<script src="https://vlibras.gov.br/app/vlibras-plugin.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

O problema foi resolvido, não sei como mas eu estava usando

```
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
```

e alterei para

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

e o plugin apareceu normalmente.